# Customising the comments layout

Tags: facebook-graph-api, comments, facebook-comments

I am trying to adapt the facebook comments system to fit the requirements for our newspaper system. We need the ability to allow a user to report a comment to us and then we will moderate the comment ourselves. We cannot let users run wild and start blocking each others' comments.

I realise that I can get the data I need to build the comments layout from the Graph API. What would I need to do to allow users to add a comment and comment on a comment?

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked here: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/comments/?